# Unexpected Token import Error CRNA

Tags: react-native, create-react-app, native-base

i am trying to install and use Native base with my CRNA app. The application runs but when I run the test it shows this error.

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
    ^^^^^^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

      at transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/transform.js:321:12)
      at Object.<anonymous> (screens/Home.js:10:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (navigation/Router.js:1:871)
```

this is my package.json ->

`"jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!react-native|native-base-shoutem-theme|@shoutem/animation|@shoutem/ui|tcomb-form-native)"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "exp": "^42.1.0",
    "expo": "^17.0.0",
    "native-base": "2.2.0",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-native": "0.44.0",
    "react-native-check-box": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-checkbox": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-hr": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.26.3",
    "react-native-material-bottom-navigation": "^0.5.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11"
  }
}`

babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-expo", "react-native"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx-source"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try running jest with --no-cache, it's not ideal but should work

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18874053)

Comment: Why does it need further clarification? I am providing an answer to the question. The provided answer solved a similar problem for me, and I am providing it as a suggestion for the quesion asked